Монтирование профиля по сети в MATE c использованием pam_mount
Для монтирования использую pam_mount, конфиг простой
<volume fstype="cifs"
        server="server"
        path="profiles/%(USER)"
        mountpoint="/home/mydomain/%(USER)"
        options="vers=3.0,nobrl,mfsymlinks,sec=krb5,cruid=%(USERUID),rw">
</volume>

Все монтируется успешно, но рабочий стол MATE дрыгается и переотрисовывается.  Смотрю люги и вижу
   mate-panel:178193): dconf-WARNING **: 07:59:14.125: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Failed to rename file “/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user.LTVHR2” to “/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed: Permission denied

    (mate-panel:178193): dconf-WARNING **: 07:59:14.340: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Failed to rename file “/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user.22TOR2” to “/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed: Permission denied

    (mate-panel:178193): dconf-WARNING **: 07:59:14.357: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Failed to rename file “/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user.HHXMR2” to “/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed: Permission denied

При этом все права на файлы и владельцы верные. Сам /home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/ и все его содержимое нужного пользователя, но почемуто операция переименования не проходит. Более того, постоянно пересоздается временный файл user.XXXXX
Нашел нечто похожее https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/1764778 ( https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-nfs-home.html.en ) добавил изменения в /etc/dconf/profile/user, но результата не дало
user-db:user
system-db:policy
system-db:local
service-db:keyfile/user

Не могу понять, что еще требуется. Допускаю, что на стороне sambы что-то, там все просто
[profiles]
         comment = Users profiles
         path = /data/samba/profiles/
         browseable = Yes
         read only = No
         vfs objects = acl_xattr

